# Arduino: Using motor to control two motors and measuring distance traveled

Tags: python, c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to control [two motors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GNFYGYQ) using a [motor driver from pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/2999) and an arduino uno which is instructed by a raspberry pi. However, I am getting errors when I try to read the encoder output so that I can measure how many full revolutions have occured so that I know how far the robot has traveled.

I would like the process to look something like this(psuedo code), while obviously my code wouldn't look like this I think it better illustrates what I am looking for:

```
1rotation = 4in
distance_goal = 36in
rot_req = 1rotation / distance_goal
if rotation_count < rot_req:
    m1.PowerOn
    m2.PowerOn
    rotation_count++
```

My actual arduino code:

```
#include "TB67H420FTG.h"
#include <QuadratureEncoder.h>
TB67H420FTG (2,3,11,4,5,10);
Encoders leftEncoder(7,6);  // Create an Encoder object name leftEncoder, using digitalpin 2 & 3
Encoders ridriverghtEncoder(15,14); // Encoder object name rightEncoder using analog pin A0 and A1 
unsigned long lastMilli = 0;

void encoderTest(){

   // print encoder count every 50 millisecond
    if(millis()-lastMilli > 50){ 
    
    long currentLeftEncoderCount = leftEncoder.getEncoderCount(); //use this anytime you need to read encoder count
    long currentRightEncoderCount = rightEncoder.getEncoderCount();//use this anytime you need to read encoder count
    
    Serial.print(currentLeftEncoderCount);
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.println(currentRightEncoderCount);
    
    lastMilli = millis();
  }
  
  }
 
void setup() 
{  
  driver.init();  // The only thing left to do is call init() so the library can initialize the pins

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
    long currentLeftEncoderCount = leftEncoder.getEncoderCount();
    long currentRightEncoderCount = rightEncoder.getEncoderCount();
    Serial.println(currentLeftEncoderCount);
    Serial.println(CurrentRightEncoderCount);
    
    String data = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.print("Command Received: " + String(data));

  // Move the motor clockwise a bit (our motor speed is valued from -100 to +100)
    if (data == "turn A right")
    driver.setMotorAPower(50);   // Set the motor speed to 50% in a clockwise direction

  // Move the motor anti-clockwise a bit (our motor speed is valued from -100 to +100)
    else if (data == "turn A left")
    driver.setMotorAPower(-50);    // Set the motor speed to 50% in a anti-clockwise direction

  // Move the motor clockwise a bit (our motor speed is valued from -100 to +100)
    if (data == "turn B right")
    driver.setMotorBPower(50);   // Set the motor speed to 50% in a clockwise direction

  // Move the motor anti-clockwise a bit (our motor speed is valued from -100 to +100)
    else if (data == "turn B left")
    driver.setMotorBPower(-50);    // Set the motor speed to 50% in a anti-clockwise direction

    else if (data == "stop A") 
    driver.motorABrake();              // Notice here we can brake motor using the motorABrake() function
  
    else if (data == "stop B") 
    driver.motorBBrake();              // Notice here we can brake motor using the motorBBrake() function
  
    else if (data == "stop All") 
    driver.brakeAll();              // Notice here we can brake both motors using the brakeAll() function
  
  else
      Serial.print("Invalid Command Received");
  }
}
```

My Raspberry Pi Code that instructs the arduino:

```py
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.reset_input_buffer()

while True:
    ser.write(b"turn A left\n")
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print("Data Received from Arduino: ",line)
    time.sleep(3)

    ser.write(b"turn A right\n")
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print("Data Received from Arduino: ",line)
    time.sleep(3)
    
    ser.write(b"turn B left\n")
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print("Data Received from Arduino: ",line)
    time.sleep(3)

    ser.write(b"turn B right\n")
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print("Data Received from Arduino: ",line)
    time.sleep(3)

    ser.write(b"stop A\n")  
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print("Data Received from Arduino: ",line)
    time.sleep(3)

    ser.write(b"stop B\n")  
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print("Data Received from Arduino: ",line)
    time.sleep(3)   
    ser.write(b"stop All\n")    
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print("Data Received from Arduino: ",line)

    time.sleep(5)
```

The error itself

```
 Arduino: 1.8.19 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"


ard_code:3:14: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 TB67H420FTG (2,3,11,4,5,10);
              ^
ard_code:3:14: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino: In function 'void encoderTest()':
ard_code:14:37: error: 'rightEncoder' was not declared in this scope
     long currentRightEncoderCount = rightEncoder.getEncoderCount();//use this anytime you need to read encoder count
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:14:37: note: suggested alternative: 'leftEncoder'
     long currentRightEncoderCount = rightEncoder.getEncoderCount();//use this anytime you need to read encoder count
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     leftEncoder
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino: In function 'void setup()':
ard_code:27:3: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
   driver.init();  // The only thing left to do is call init() so the library can initialize the pins
   ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:27:3: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
   driver.init();  // The only thing left to do is call init() so the library can initialize the pins
   ^~~~~~
   div
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino: In function 'void loop()':
ard_code:37:37: error: 'rightEncoder' was not declared in this scope
     long currentRightEncoderCount = rightEncoder.getEncoderCount();
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:37:37: note: suggested alternative: 'leftEncoder'
     long currentRightEncoderCount = rightEncoder.getEncoderCount();
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     leftEncoder
ard_code:39:20: error: 'CurrentRightEncoderCount' was not declared in this scope
     Serial.println(CurrentRightEncoderCount);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:39:20: note: suggested alternative: 'currentRightEncoderCount'
     Serial.println(CurrentRightEncoderCount);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    currentRightEncoderCount
ard_code:46:5: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
     driver.setMotorAPower(50);   // Set the motor speed to 50% in a clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:46:5: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
     driver.setMotorAPower(50);   // Set the motor speed to 50% in a clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
     div
ard_code:50:5: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
     driver.setMotorAPower(-50);    // Set the motor speed to 50% in a anti-clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:50:5: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
     driver.setMotorAPower(-50);    // Set the motor speed to 50% in a anti-clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
     div
ard_code:54:5: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
     driver.setMotorBPower(50);   // Set the motor speed to 50% in a clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:54:5: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
     driver.setMotorBPower(50);   // Set the motor speed to 50% in a clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
     div
ard_code:58:5: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
     driver.setMotorBPower(-50);    // Set the motor speed to 50% in a anti-clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:58:5: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
     driver.setMotorBPower(-50);    // Set the motor speed to 50% in a anti-clockwise direction
     ^~~~~~
     div
ard_code:61:5: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
     driver.motorABrake();              // Notice here we can brake motor using the motorABrake() function
     ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:61:5: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
     driver.motorABrake();              // Notice here we can brake motor using the motorABrake() function
     ^~~~~~
     div
ard_code:64:5: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
     driver.motorBBrake();              // Notice here we can brake motor using the motorBBrake() function
     ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:64:5: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
     driver.motorBBrake();              // Notice here we can brake motor using the motorBBrake() function
     ^~~~~~
     div
ard_code:67:5: error: 'driver' was not declared in this scope
     driver.brakeAll();              // Notice here we can brake both motors using the brakeAll() function
     ^~~~~~
/home/garb/Desktop/test/ard_code/ard_code.ino:67:5: note: suggested alternative: 'div'
     driver.brakeAll();              // Notice here we can brake both motors using the brakeAll() function
     ^~~~~~
     div
exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before numeric constant


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I know what the question is here. Are you just asking for someone to write some code for you?

Comment: @john, sorry - actually forgot to include the error message - no I just need help debugging this error.

Comment: OK edit the question to include the error message, and please also indicate which line of code generates the error.

Comment: @john, yup will do

Comment: Take a look at the example code that come with the library to understand how to use the library. `TB67H420FTG` is a Class, to use the Class, you need to create an instance of a Class with `TB67H420FTG myMotor1`. Furthermore, as far as I can see is that the construct only allows two parameters `TB67H420FTG motor(directionA, directionB)`. See the [source code](https://github.com/chrisalbertson/tb67h420ftg/blob/master/Tb67h402ftg.h#L48);

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a description of the problems with your code. Also bear in mind that I know C++ but know nothing about Arduino.

I'm not sure what you expect `TB67H420FTG (2,3,11,4,5,10);` to do, but `TB67H420FTG`  is the name of a class, and should be used in a similar manner to `Encoders` on the next line. You must create a `TB67H420FTG` object. That can be done in one of two ways `TB67H420FTG motor;` or `TB67H420FTG motor(a, b);` where `motor` is the name of the object and `a` and `b` are integers parameters indicating the motor direction (whatever that means).

Later in the code you start to use a variable called `driver` e.g. `driver.setMotorAPower(50);` which has not been declared anywhere. Obviously that needs a declaration though I have no idea what that would be.

To be honest the code looks like you have just combined various pieces of code you have found on the internet. It also looks nothing like the pseudo code you posted. It seems you are going to have to spend some time learning basic C++. It's not a language you can just pick up as you go along.